# Route outgoing connections from a docker container through a specific IP

Tags: iptables, docker

I have a docker host machine with a single physical network interface (eth0) and multiple IP addresses assigned to it using IP aliasing (eth0:1, eth0:2, eth0:3).

I would like to run several docker containers so that each of them is using it's own IP address for outgoing calls to the internet. Preferably they would be also reachable on the same IP when connecting from container to container.

How do I setup docker and iptables for this to work? And with what parameters I need to run each of the containers afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

eth0 -> 192.168.0.1

eth0:1 -> 192.168.0.2

eth0:2 -> 192.168.0.3

eth0:3 -> 192.168.0.4

docker run --name=web01 -p 192.168.0.1:80:80 ....

docker run --name=web02 -p 192.168.0.2:80:80 ....

docker run --name=web03 -p 192.168.0.3:80:80 ....

docker run --name=web04 -p 192.168.0.4:80:80 ....

They will be created DNAT rules:

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 0   0 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.1           tcp dpt:80 to:172.17.0.1:80

pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 0   0 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.2           tcp dpt:80 to:172.17.0.2:80

...

traffic generated container falls under the rule:

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 430M packets, 26G bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 0   0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0

p.s.

In linux we can use many ip without alias

ip a a 192.168.0.1/24 dev eth0

ip a a 192.168.0.2/24 dev eth0
....

Comment: That answers the question about reachability from outside, and thanks for the hint regarding using many IPs without alias. However it does not help with providing the specific IP for outgoing calls from a container.

I managed to get it working by running: `iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.2 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.3`

However this approach requires me to know also the docker IP upfront and me running it when I start the container.

Is there a feature in docker which would allow me to specify `192.168.0.3` on the command line and it would add the iptables rule itself?

Comment: You can use --ip for docker run, so you can set the ip container, but nat rule will have to be assigned manually. Maybe I'm wrong, but the other way I do not find. For complex configurations I use https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework, or rather his fork

Comment: @user2288258 hey wanted to write -A POSTROUTING not -D POSTROUTING

Answer (score 1):

### Desired State

Multiple docker containers, each one uses specefic host IP from our single network interface which:

1. receives its traffic only on its host IP
2. sends traffic to the internet on behalf of its host IP

### Solution

For (1), we can use the [docker port binding](https://docs.docker.com/network/#published-ports) like this (This will create the `DNAT` iptable rules for routing traffic to the related container):

```bash
docker run -p 192.168.1.101:80:80
docker run -p 192.168.1.102:80:80
...
```

For (2), we can use `SNAT` iptable rules to change the IP header of outgoing traffic (see [this link](https://gist.github.com/tomasinouk/eec152019311b09905cd) for more examples):

```bash
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s 172.18.0.1 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.101
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s 172.18.0.2 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.102
...
```

**Note**: Use the above `iptables` commands with caution. Also, be aware that those commands will insert rules at the very first order of the `POSTROUTING` chain of `nat` table.

I tried to wrap-up one of the current working solutions for this type of problem. I hope it helps!